# Using params from nested attributes in a validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building a simple accounting application.  Transactions have many entries, and each entry belongs to one transaction.  Each entry is either a debit or a credit entry.  The sum of the 'amounts' field for all the debits must equal the sum of all the credits for each transaction.  So in my transaction model, I have the following:

Transaction.rb

```
attr_accessible :entries_attributes
has_many :entries
accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries

validate :entries_sum_to_zero

private

    def entries_sum_to_zero
        errors.add(:base, "Debits and credits must balance.") unless self.entries.where(:entry_type => 'Credit').sum(:amount) == self.entries.where(:entry_type => 'Debit').sum(:amount)
    end
```

But this doesn't work.  It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't stop the transaction and all of the entries from saving to the database if the condition is not met.  I thought it might have to do with the fact that the 'amount' from the entries model is in the params hash for entries_attributes.  Is that the case?  IF so, how do I rewrite the above code to sum the amounts in the entries_attributes params hash before the transaction is saved?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I also tried this but it did not seem to work either:

```
before_save :entries_sum_to_zero

private
    def entries_sum_to_zero
       if self.entries.where(:entry_type => 'Credit').sum(:amount) != self.entries.where(:entry_type => 'Debit').sum(:amount)
           errors.add(:base, "Debits and credits must balance.")
           return false
       end
    end
```

UPDATE 2:

I ultimately got it to work by moving the validation into the controller.  But how do I move this back into the model so I can keep the validations in one place?

```
def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @transaction = @company.transactions.new(params[:transaction])
    sum_of_debits = 0
    sum_of_credits = 0      
    params[:transaction]['entries_attributes'].each do |k,v|
        sum_of_debits += v['amount'].to_i if v['entry_type'] == "Debit"
        sum_of_credits += v['amount'].to_i if v['entry_type'] == "Credit"
    end
    if sum_of_credits != sum_of_debits
        flash[:error] = "Debits and Credits must balance."
        render 'new'
    else        
        if @transaction.save
            flash[:success] = "Transaction added"
            redirect_to company_path(@company)
        else
            render 'new'
        end   
    end       
end
```

Comment: you should call `entries_sum_to_zero` in a before_save callback (and return false) ;)

Comment: That didn't seem to work either.  I updated my question with how I changed it to use before_save.  Did I do something wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in validate method. You asking database for two sums and validation goes well, because your new entries does not exists in database yet. You have to check only entries_attributes (since we can assume, then everything is ok in database)

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but how do I do that?

Comment: Something like iterate over entries_attributes, check entry_type and add amount to some variable

bad and dirty solution

    credit = 0.0
    debit = 0.0
    entries_attributes.each do |e|
      credit += e['amount'] if e['entry_type'] == 'Credit'
      debit += e['amount'] if e['entry_type'] == 'Debit'
    end

    errors.add... unless credit == debit

Comment: Thanks, but that link didn't work.  It took me to a page that said "oh no".

Comment: Rails said that entries_attributes was an undefined local variable or method when I used your code.  Why is that?  Any ideas on how to fix it?  Thanks.